# React Router history, location, and match objects not available when using Route render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have the following `Route` which renders when the path is matched:

```
<Route exact path="/create-team" render={() => <TeamNameCard/>}/>
```

This properly renders the `<TeamNameCard/>` component, however the `match`, `location`, and `history` props are not available in `this.props`.

However, when rendering the component using the following, those props *are* available:

```
<Route exact path="/create-team" component={TeamNameCard}/>
```

According to the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func), all render methods should receive these same props. Why is this not working as expected?

**EDIT:** I've noticed that the following syntax seems to give me access to the needed route props:

```
render={(props) => <TeamNameCard {...props} />
```

I've yet to see this before. Is this correct, or is there a better way?

Comment: It's correct. The link you posted has an example that passes props the same way

Comment: A better way is to use `component={TeamNameCard}` is you don't explicitly need to pass some custom pros to the component, otherwise pass the default props with the `render` as mentioned in the answer to the duplicate question

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thank you for noting the duplicate, it explained the answer well.